# Copy file from Azure DevOps repo to a Windows 2016 vm

Tags: azure-devops

In my Azure DevOps pipeline, I want to create a task which will copy a file from ADO repo to c:\ of the vm. Is this possible and if not what could be a solution?

Comment: Have you checked the following reply? Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

Try using "[Windows Machine File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops)" or "[Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops)" in your pipeline to copy a file to your VM.

### Solution 2

Create a deployment group and run "Registration script" on your VM:

[image]

Then from release pipeline create a deployment group job and write a script to copy files:

[image]